# How to use hilt for testing in a multi module android project?

Tags: dagger-2, android-testing, dagger-hilt, android-multi-module

I’ve couple of questions when trying to use hilt for testing in a multi-module project:

1. Say I’ve a feature module which declared some interface and its classes depend upon that interface. The implementation of this interface is provided in the `:app` module (or any module below `:feature`) which is not available to feature module. How can I write tests for feature module in the feature module itself? As feature module don’t have binding for that interface, it throws missing binding error. Sure I can provide fake/mock dependencies for them, but what if say I’ve 50 such interfaces whose bindings exist below that feature module? Providing fakes doesn’t look scalable here
2. How to replace only a single dependency in other module?
3. If we need to use `@UninstallModules` for #2, how will you do so when the original dagger module is `internal`?

I've tried using local dagger module inside `@HiltAndroidTest` annotated class, but without `@UninstallModules`, it doesn't work. And I don't have access to original module since it was `internal` to that gradle module